# Parent does not contain constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

If I have this code in C#:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    private int x;
    public Parent(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public abstract void foo;
}  
public class Child
{
    public override void foo()
    {  
        x = x + 10;
    }
}
```

I get error that:

> Parent does not contain constructor that takes 0 arguments.

How can I fix it, without creating non-parametric constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a constructor in `Child`, e.g.

```
public Child(int x) : base(x)
{
}
```

Constructors are *not* inherited - but if you don't supply any constructors at all, the C# compiler tries to create one equivalent to this:

```
public Child() : base()
{
}
```

That's what's failing here, because there isn't a parameterless base constructor to call.

Your derived class constructor doesn't have to have the same parameters as the base class constructor of course - so long as it passes appropriate arguments to a base constructor, that's fine. For example, you could write:

```
public Child() : base(0) // Default to x = 0
{
}
```

See my [article on constructors](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

By manually invoking Parent's constructor:

```
public class Child: Parent {
    public Child( ) 
        : base(0) { }

    public override void foo( ) {  
        x = x + 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is an Implicit call to a constructor with zero argument.

So you need to add an explicit call:

```
public Child(int x) : base(x)
{
}
```

Or instead, you can add zero argument contructor in parent itself:

```
public parent() { }
```